# CanStop = false, but I can't start the service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am making a service to put on my kid's computer, to make sure that they can't stop Qustodio, and they are quite tech-savvy. They know how to stop a service by going to Run >> services.msc, and I need to make the service NOT_STOPPABLE, like Kaspersky. But when I add the line: `CanStop = false;`, I can't start the service and it gives me an error. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace MyFirstService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        ServiceController qengine = new ServiceController("qengine");
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 5000; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;
            CanStop = false;
        }
        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            qengine.Start();
            WriteToFile("qengine attemped start at: " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"and it gives me an error"_ which error?

Comment: It just says there was an exception.

Comment: Then you need to find exactly which exception is thrown and where. Try to inspect system log, or use a debugger. There is static method [Debugger.Launch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch) which may help you with this.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I was calling CanStop = false; after the service had started, and I can't do that